# Determine that H is a subspace of R^3

Tags: linear-algebra

the problem is given below:

[image]

I can see that the set contain zero vector by saying:

⟨c,0,c⟩=⟨0,0,0⟩

c=0

but how to finde if the set is closed by addition of vectors and closed by multiplication of real-valued scalar ?

Comment: Every span is a subspace, no matter what it is a span of. (This is sometimes part of the _definition_ of span, sometimes an early theorem).

Comment: Both your thoughts and the answer by Emilio seem to assume that the problem says $$ H = \Biggl\{ \begin{bmatrix}c\\0\\c\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert\, x\in \mathbb R\Biggr\}$$ instead of what it actually says. If it _actually_ says $$ H = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\\c\end{bmatrix}\right\} \text{ with }c\in\mathbb R$$ then $H$ is something that _depends on $c$_ -- and you can't just set $c=0$ to prove that the $H$ you get when $c=2$ is a subspace ...

Comment: How to then find the zero vector?

Comment: x @AdiT: What is your definition of $\operatorname{span}$?

Comment: linear combinations of v1 to vp.

Comment: x @AdiT: Then you can always get the zero vector as the _empty linear combination_ -- or, if that unsettles you, as $0\cdot v_1$.

Comment: Aaa yes you are right. and closed by addition?

Comment: x @AdiT: If you have two linear combinations, the distributive law will allow you to rearrange their sum so it end up being a single linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By definition  the span of a set of vectors is the intersection of all the subspaces that contain the set, so it is a subspace.

If you want to prove that all vectors of the form $[c,0,c]^T$ are a subspace   than take two vectors in $H$ as: $[a,0,a]^T$ and $[b,0,b]^T$, than:

$$
[a,0,a]^T+k[b,0,b]^T=[a+kb,0,a+kb]^T
$$

Comment: The comments of@Henning point out a wery important point so I've modified my answer.